Create (CSV) External Table From Multiple Files in Sub-directories
Let's say I have a dataset that is ingested on a daily basis and placed within a timestamped sub-directory in a particular location in my data lake (Azure Data Lake Storage). The directory structure will look something like this:

Each file placed in the sub-directories will have the same name (iris.csv) and of course, the same schema.
I want to be able to create an external table in Unity Catalog (via Azure Databricks) using this location. An external location has already been created by pointing to the main storage container within the storage account.
I am able to read this data (via the external location) without any problem:
SELECT *
FROM CSV.`abfss://data@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/raw_iris/*/*`

However, I am not able to create an external table on this location and I feel that the error message displayed is somewhat misleading.
Here is the code that I tried running to create the table:
CREATE TABLE <catalog>.<schema>.<table>
USING CSV
OPTIONS (
  header "true",
  inferSchema "true"
)
LOCATION 'abfss://data<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/raw_iris/*/*'

I have also tried supplying the schema:
CREATE TABLE <catalog>.<schema>.<table>(
  sepal_length DOUBLE,
  sepal_width DOUBLE,
  petal_length DOUBLE,
  petal_width DOUBLE,
  variety STRING
)
USING CSV
OPTIONS (
  header "true",
  inferSchema "true"
)
LOCATION 'abfss://data@<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/raw_iris/*/*'

Unfortunately, at every turn I get the following error message:
KeyProviderException: Failure to initialize configuration for storage account <storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:696)

At first glance, this seems to be an issue with permissions, but that would not make much sense because I am able to read the data without an issue.
What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to do this within Databricks and Unity Catalog?

Select can be misleading as it could be pulling the top few rows. Can you run a select query that uses all rows like count(*) or some group bys to make sure no issues with adls perm

I am able to get a count without a problem. The SELECT query also returns all of the data in my dataset.

It turns out that all you need to do in order to achieve this is to add the recursiveFileLookup option to the query:
CREATE TABLE <catalog>.<schema>.<table>
USING CSV
OPTIONS (
  header "true",
  inferSchema "true"
  recursiveFileLookup "true"
)
LOCATION 'abfss://data<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/raw_iris/'

With this, the location (or path) should point to the root path of the dataset as shown above.
